# How to get IPv6 address of vm from C++ code?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ipv6

I have a VM and I want to get IPv6 address from C++ code.
I have found [getaddrinfo](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getaddrinfo&category=3&russian=0) function but I don't understand what parameters to use to get IPv6 address.
I have tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    addrinfo hint, *res = NULL, *p = NULL;
    int err;
    memset(&hint, 0, sizeof hint);
    hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    err = getaddrinfo(NULL, "http", &hint, &res);

    std::cout << res->ai_canonname;

    return 0;
}
```

but get `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)` error. How to get IPv6 address of vm from C++ code?

Comment: did the call work (you didnt chekc err), caonname can be null, thats why it would fail even if the get worked. The address in in ai_sockaddr

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if `getaddrinfo()` succeeds before you use its result.

Also, `res->ai_canonname` does not contain the IP address you are looking for.  It is stored in `res->ai_addr` instead.  But, it is stored in a binary form (as a `sockaddr_in6` struct).  To get a textual form, you can pass the binary IP to `getnameinfo()` or `inet_ntop()` or other equivalent  function.

Also, `getaddrinfo()` returns a linked-list of IPs.  A machine can have multiple IPs installed, so you should walk the whole list printing out each IP that is available.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
//#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    addrinfo hint = {}, *res;

    hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;

    int err = getaddrinfo(NULL, "http", &hint, &res);
    if (err != 0) {
        std::cerr << "getaddrinfo failed, error " << err << '\n';
    }
    else {
        char ip[NI_MAXHOST];

        for (addrinfo *p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {

            if (getnameinfo(p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen, ip, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) != 0)
                continue;

            /* alternatively:
            if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(p->ai_addr)->sin6_addr), ip, NI_MAXHOST) == NULL)
                continue;
            */

            std::cout << ip << '\n';
        }

        freeaddrinfo(res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, that being said, `getaddrinfo()` is not the best choice for retreiving the local IPs.  If your platform supports it, you should use `getifaddrs()` or equivalent instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
//#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifaddrs *res = NULL;

    int err = getifaddrs(&res);
    if (err < 0) {
        std::cerr << "getifaddrs failed, error " << err << '\n';
    }
    else {
        char ip[NI_MAXHOST];

        for (ifaddrs *p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ifa_next) {
            if ((p->ifa_addr == NULL) || (p->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_INET6))
                continue;

            if (getnameinfo(p->ifa_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in6), ip, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) != 0)
                continue;

            /* alternatively:
            if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(res->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr), ip, NI_MAXHOST) == NULL)
                continue;
            */

            std::cout << ip << '\n';
        }

        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got several result addresses, but I don't really understand what they mean.
Could you please comment or maybe advise some article/tutorial to read to understand what all these addresses mean?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. You asked how to retrieve them. I answered. Understanding what they represent should be posted as a separate question. One question per post, please.